# Finding a string in array

Tags: javascript

I was working with Hacker Rank tool.

Over there, all the input given by user is a string

So the input given by the user will be

`1,2,3,4,5` which could be taken as `"1"."2","3","4"`

Now, I want to convert it into array of numbers

```
if (input) {
 if (input.split(',').indexOf("") > - 1) { console.log("invalid input") }
  else { input =  input.split(',').map(Number);   }
} else {
  input =  [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 5, 9, 1, 2, 8]; 
}
```

Here, I am checking if there is an input specified, if yes it will take that input defined by user or else it will take the input defined by me as `inpurt`

Now, the input given by the user can be string as well in which case I want to throw an error saying "**invalid input"**

For which I thought of something like this

```
 if (input.split(',').indexOf("") > - 1) { console.log("invalid input")
```

But that doesn't appear to be working, can someone help me in figuring out how can I do it?

**Update:** When I say input given by user could be string, I mean he can give something like "1, 2, 3, abc" which is invalid input (since it contains abc)

**Example:** 1, 2, 3, 4 when consoled log gives "1, 2, 3, 4" which is a string basically having numbers ( **a valid input**)

but

Input of this

1, 2, 3, 4abc is **invalid input** because it consist of `4abc` which isn't number

So when I do

```
 input =  input.split(',').map(Number);
```

for the above, it will probably give me

```
[1,2,3,NaN]
```

Comment: `inpurt `  in `inpurt =  input.split(',').map(Number);` is a typo, right?

Comment: nope. I am storing the `input` value in `inpurt` No Specific reason though, Can do something like this as well `if (!input) input = [1, 2, 3, 5, 1, 5, 9, 1, 2, 8]`

Comment: I don't understand what you mean "the input given by the user can be string as well ".  Earlier you said all input would be a string?

Comment: you can use inpurt.push(input)

Comment: @Paul updated the post

Comment: `4abc` is a hexadecimal number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paul's answer is almost correct. In the filter function, though, you need to also parse the number and then check if it's not a `NaN`.

```
const numbers = input.split(',')
  .filter(n => !isNaN(parseInt(n, 10)))
```

Comment: why that `parseInt`? totally needless.

Comment: Sorry. Old habit; used to doing it in one go without using the map.

Comment: Still, `parseInt` is less reliable than using the `Number` construct. Do that with eg `'1,001,2,3'` as input. The `001` is not valid in OP's context., but is in yours code.

Comment: what does n, 10 in parse int means?

Comment: n is the string you are trying to parse while 10 is the `radix` and a optional number (from 2 to 36) that represents the numeral system to be used. According to https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now I see what you need, thanks.

It's a pretty simple check to filter out bad numbers:

```
const numbers = input.split(',').map(Number)
const filtered = numbers.filter(n => !isNaN(n))
```

So in this case, numbers which can't be parsed by Number() will return `NaN`.  `NaN` is falsy, so will be filtered out, and so the `filtered` array has only numbers. To be clear `!!n` just means to evaluate n as a strict boolean; so falsy becomes a real false.  It works the same if you just used `n` but I think it's more explicit to cast it as a bool

If you wan to throw an error, you can test:

```
if (numbers.length > filtered.length) throw new Error('Invalid Input');
```

Comment: This will disallow `0` even though it's a perfectly valid `number`.

Comment: to exclude `NaN`, you could use `.filter(n -> !Number.isNaN(n))` instead because yours approach excludes `0`.

Comment: Good catch, thanks @KarelG, I was obviously trying to be too clever

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like below

```
var number = ['1', '2', 'a', 'b', '4', '5', '7']
function check() {
   var s = 0;
   for (var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
     if(!isNaN(arguments[i])){
            number[s] = arguments[i];
        console.log(number[s++]);
     }
   }
}

check(...number);
```

Answer (score 0):

oKay, So I am using since I didn't want to method which iterates over an array rather wanted a single iteration to do the Job.

The above answers are amazing but for some reason I thought sharing my answer as well.

```
  if (input) {
       input = input.map(number => {
           if (!Number(number)) console.log("Error: Contains a non number") 
           if (Number(number)) return Number(number)
       }) else {
           input = [7, 8, 4, 9, 9, 15, 3, 1, 10];
   }
```